# DecimalFormatter with a custom pattern

Tags: java, kotlin, number-formatting, formatter

I'm creating a custom formatter where I want to avoid using the `Locale`, so having a `groupingSeparator`, `decimalDelimiter` configure the `decimalFormatter` with the configured values.

But when I want to modify the `groupingSeparator` and `decimalSeparator` looks like I have to define a `pattern` but I don't know how the price would be, I know the max that could be 9.999,99.

I'm able to change the "." and "," dynamically with my settings, but I'm facing some problems when for instance the price is 0,3 if I have the

```
maximumFractionDigits = 2
minimumFractionDigits = 2
```

If the price is 0,3 the output should be 0,30, also if the price is 4 the output should be 4,00.

I'm using this as a pattern : `#.###,##"` but is giving an exception

> Malformed pattern "#.###,##"

Having this pattern `applyPattern("###,###")` most of cases work except the 0,30 that it shows ,30 and is wrong I guess the problem is the `pattern`...

So the thing is the maximum number to display is :
9.999,99
And the minimum number to display is
0.00

Here's my formatter

```
val decimalFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance() as DecimalFormat
        return decimalFormat.apply {
            applyPattern("####,##") <-- wondering what to put here
            isGroupingUsed = true <-- because I accept thousand price
            maximumFractionDigits = maxDecimal
            minimumFractionDigits = minDecimal
            decimalFormatSymbols = decimalFormatSymbols.apply {
                groupingSeparator = groupingSep
                decimalSeparator = decimalSep
            }
            negativePrefix = "" <-- To don't show the currency
            positivePrefix = "" <-- To don't show the currency
        }.format(amount)
```

Using this `applyPattern("0.#")` works for the case of 0, but it doesn't works for cases of thousands even if I add the grouping separator as a "," it won't put it and print the thousand without grouping separator like
expected = 1,234
actual = 1234

Comment: Shouldn’t the pattern always use . for decimal and , for grouping?

Answer (score 0):

Use `"#,##0.00"`. The # means a digit should be displayed there except for trailing/leading zeros. The 0 means a digit is always displayed, even if it is a trailing/leading zero. The number of decimal places in the formatted string is equal to the total number of 0s after the dot, so in this example 2.

Comment: I'm using this `#,##0.##` what's the difference? Because for this it works too...

Comment: This will output a number without decimal digits if the input doesn't have decimal digits. For example 4 -> displayed as `4` and not as `4,00`